# Regeneration output analysis method in SimJava

Tags: java, performance, simulation

I am implementing a simulation system in SimJava 2. I want to terminate the simulation run time according to the regeneration method. In SimJava 2 there is the independent replications method as termination condition but i can't find the regeneration method.

Do you have any idea how to implement it in SimJava 2?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note - I'm not a user of SimJava. I know a fair amount about discrete event simulation, and I skimmed the tutorial.

It looks like you'll want to define an event that corresponds to the system landing in a state that's recognizably the end of a regeneration interval.  Then [terminate your model when you've seen the desired number of those events](http://www.icsa.inf.ed.ac.uk/research/groups/hase/simjava/guide/tutorial.html#7.3).  You have to (properly) define suitable regeneration points, which are model dependent.  For a single server queue, you get regeneration points whenever the queue is empty and the server is idle.  For multiple queue systems, it requires all queues be empty and all servers be idle simultaneously.  Not all systems are regenerative, but if yours is the more complex the system is, the sparser regeneration points are. This in turn means that your run lengths are random variables, and there's no guarantee that a given run of your simulation will terminate by any particular time. It's for these reasons that the regenerative method, while mathematically elegant, is much less common in practice than independent replication/deletion or batch means.